# Concatenating arguments & redirections to a sudo command from a variable causes errors

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that install multiple `sudo apt-get` and `systemctl enable` afterwards.

The full command is `sudo apt-get install ssh -y 1>/dev/null 2>>test.txt`

Works fine. But if I use

```
FORCE=" -y 1>/dev/null 2>>test.txt"
sudo apt-get install ssh${FORCE}
```

I get error Multiple Error E.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package 1>/dev 
E: Unable to locate package 2>>test.txt 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2>>test.txt' E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2>>test.txt'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Multiple Error E*? Show the output, please.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add extra information to your question. Make sure it's properly formatted (like `\`\`\`` for code and log text).

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You can't store syntax in strings. Don't try; [the workarounds compromise security](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Use _functions_ when you want to store and reuse code.

Answer (score 1):

The order-of-operations during bash execution means that variables values are substituted only **after** syntax parsing is complete. This is a good thing: If it were otherwise, a variable with a filename could do arbitrary redirection or run arbitrary commands if that filename contained syntax like `$(rm -rf ~)`.

Instead of using a string-type variable, define a function:

```
force() { "$@" -y >/dev/null 2>>test.txt; }
force sudo apt-get install ssh
```

---

BTW, you might also consider:

```
forceApt() { sudo apt-get "$@" -y >/dev/null 2>>test.txt; }
forceApt install ssh
```

...substituting content at the beginning as well as the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will performance be a factor here? I have technically 30 apt-get to call

Comment: Functions are very fast to run -- there's no subprocess overhead involved when they're constructed properly -- so for the use case above, there won't be any measurable impact.

Comment: @Dennis, ...btw, if you're worried about how long the process takes you might consider installing more than one package at a time. `apt-get install ssh something-else`, f/e, will install both `ssh` and `something-else` in a single invocation. Because it's able to download multiple packages at a time (and do only one transaction in the package management database) there's some time savings that way.